# how put values of two columns in select2 - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, jquery-select2

I have a form serviced by select2.js

In my controller I generate a var with select content:

```
$gau = array(null => 'Gautor...') + Gauthor::orderBy('surname','asc')->lists('surname', 'id')->all();
```

In my view I do this:

```
{!! Form::select('gauthor_id', $gau, Session::get('aut'), array('id'=>'gauthor_id')) !!}
```

In my table I have two columns: `surname` and `firstnames`.

In my `Gauthor` model I merge them like this:

```
public function getFullnameAttribute()
{
    return $this->firstnames . ' ' . $this->surname;
}
```

in order to display the value in this way `$o->fullname` in my view files.

**What I try to do:** 
I want to see full name in my select box. How to do it without creating another column with full name in my database?

What I have tried:
I tried to replace `surname` with `fullname` in the controller, but it would be too easy. I got SQL error: Column "fullname" not found

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this code, didnt test it

```
Gauthor::selectRaw('id, CONCAT(firstnames, " ", surname) as fullname')
->orderBy('fullname','asc')->lists('fullname', 'id');
```

`selectRaw('id, CONCAT(firstnames, " ", surname) as fullname')` will select the `id` and the `fullname` *(which is concat by firstname & surname)*. and then you can list those two by `->lists('fullname', 'id')`.

Comment: :) yeas oky, and for the best practice you can do this query inside the controller or repository (if you'r using repository pattern). :)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I get empty select. I have tried with and without the `->all()` tag

Comment: Do you have the select options but the option text which is `fullname` is empty? OR you cant get any options in the select (no options)?

Comment: THe select seems to contain all the options, but there is no text - i can select empty options, though. Anyway, Someone outside SO just helped me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

An extra `->get()` did the magic. The full line should look like this:

```
$gau = array(null => 'Gautor...') + Gauthor::orderBy('surname','asc')->get()->lists('fullname', 'id')->all();
```

If you want to include the `id` of the model, then you need to include the following option within the `select2` invocation:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").select2({
            templateResult: function(state) {
                if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
                return  state.id + ' - ' + state.text;
            }
        });

    });
```

instead of this:

```
  $("select").select2();
```